# Clearing javascript intervals on pageChange/pageRemove in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Below is some simplified code of a pageinit event in jQueryMobile. I create a function and declare an interval on it but I cannot clear the interval on a pageremove event. It returns null on this event but the interval continues on other pages.

```
var interval_geoLocationParse;
$(document).delegate("#agriMapperGeoLocationAdd", "pageremove", function(){
   console.log(interval_geoLocationParse); // gives null interval is not cleared
   clearInterval(interval_geoLocationParse);
   });

$(document).delegate("#agriMapperGeoLocationAdd", "pageinit", function() { 
   function geoLocationParse(){
      //some function
      }
   interval_geoLocationParse = setInterval(geoLocationParse, 20000);
   console.log(interval_geoLocationParse); // gives interval ID
   });
```

Comment: Which JQM version are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 1.4.3